# Request channel timing out when calling to web services under asp.net core

Tags: web-services, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

I have requests to web services made from asp.net core web site timing out on developer machine (in production they work fine).
Specifically the first request almost always times out, but the one made immediately after it tends to succeed.

In logs there is a following error:

```
{
  "Message": "The request channel timed out attempting to send after 00:01:00. I
ncrease the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTime
out value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a po
rtion of a longer timeout.",
  "Data": {},
  "InnerException": {
    "Message": "The HTTP request to '<service address here>' has exceeded the allotted timeout of 00:01:00. The time allotted to this
operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.",
    "Data": {},
    "StackTrace": "   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpC
lientRequestChannel.HttpClientChannelAsyncRequest.<SendRequestAsync>d__13.MoveNe
xt()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNot
ification(Task task)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.<RequestAsync>d__35.MoveNext()
",
    "Source": "System.Private.ServiceModel",
    "HResult": -2146233083
  },
  "StackTrace": "   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.<RequestAsync
>d__35.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNot
ification(Task task)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.<RequestAsyncInternal>d__34.Mo
veNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNot
ification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.TaskHelpers.WaitForCompletionNoSpin[TResult](Task`1 task)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeS
pan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message messag
e, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean on
eway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan tim
eout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(MethodCall
methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(MethodInfo targetM
ethod, Object[] args)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Reflection.DispatchProxyGenerator.Invoke(Object[] args)
...
```

This behavior is the same across different web servers started locally (kestrel, iis express, iis), but in production (in mono docker container) there is no such problem.

Any help is much appreciated!